# Переменное число параметров

Tags: python

Не могу кое что понять. Тема "переменное число параметров", пример такой:

> Когда мы объявляем параметр со звёздочкой (например, `*param`), все позиционные аргументы начиная с этой позиции и до конца будут собраны в кортеж)под именем `param`.

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count+=number
    for key in keywords:
        count+= keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(2,2,2, vagerta=2 , fls=3))
```

С какой позиции? И как понять до конца, какого конца? То же и те же вопросы и про параметр с `**`.

И почему здесь:

```
for key in keywords:
    count+= keywords[key]
```

такая запись? Т.е если писать `key` то ошибка? Почему `keywords` и потом `[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

В данной функции:

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count+=number
    for key in keywords:
        count+= keywords[key]
    return count
```

`*numbers` - все позиционные аргументы, начиная со второго (первый - `initial`, `5` по умолчанию)

`**keywords` - все именованные аргументы, идущие *после* позиционных аргументов. В Python они представлены как словарь - поэтому и обращаемся к ним как к словарю

---

**UPDATE:**

чтобы понять границы `*numbers` и `**keywords` можно добавить примитивную отладку в функцию:

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    print(f"initial:\t{initial}")
    print(f"*numbers:\t{numbers}")
    print(f"**keywords:\t{keywords}")
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count+=number
    for key in keywords:
        count+= keywords[key]
    return count
```

запуск:

```
In [226]: print(total(1,2,3,4,5, parm1=6, parm2=7))
initial:        1
*numbers:       (2, 3, 4, 5)
**keywords:     {'parm1': 6, 'parm2': 7}
28
```

Comment: print(total(2,2,2, vagerta=2 , fls=3)) как тогда понять аткую запиись в строке вывода? где какая запятая . initial = 5 потом запятая . что происходит ? где какая запятая . если я напишу 2,2,2,2,2,2 все они соберутся в кортеж . а в numbers пишем vagerta=2 тогда это просто 2. По большому счету все просто прибавляется и выходит одно число.  В общем я все равно не понял. Как это работает и почему именно так.

Comment: @МагомедАзизов, два раза перечитал ваш комментарий, но так и не понял что вы хотите спросить...

Comment: если все позиционные аргументы начиная с  позиции(*numbers)  и до конца будут собраны в кортеж.. Где его границы в вызове с параметром? print(total(2,2,2, vagerta=2 , fls=3)) запятая ? если да тогда где конец запятой одного из параметров?

Comment: если я пишу просто print(total(45,545,45,454,54,)) то оно суммируется  так же как и такая запись print(total(2,2,2, vagerta=2 , fls=3)). Но где граница параметра ? Запятая что ли ? какая

Comment: @МагомедАзизов, дополнил ответ

Comment: короче никто ничего не понимает в самом легком языке . ..

Comment: Как же объяснить чтоб человек понял? а не робот?. Там три параметра а при вызове пишут много параметров. так ? где в запятых граница каждого из трех параметров ?

Comment: Ты уже так запутал что я даже не понимаю что я хотел узнать . Наверное на форумах специально включают дурочку и задают 1000 вопросов и никогда ни одного ответа. Чтоб человек бросил это . Помню я потратил 7 лет на форумах чтоб освоить denwer и почему php скрипты не запускаются . Одни вопросы. Потом я отрыл для себя Open Server .

Comment: @МагомедАзизов, боюсь я врядли смогу объяснить еще более подробно / доходчиво. Рекомендую начать с самого элементарного учебника по Python...

Comment: Я вставил твой код чтоб узнать где граница параметра и после вызова такого  print(total(45,45,454,65,656,5431,8))выходит 

initial: 45
*numbers: (45, 454, 65, 656, 5431, 8)
**keywords: {}
6704
теперь в initial: 45 только одна цифра 
в *numbers: (45, 454, 65, 656, 5431, 8) все включая и 45
а в **keywords: {} ничего. 
Не понял. И это не включая вопроса о записи print(f"initial:\t{initial}")что за f?

Comment: Ладно друг спасибо все равно . Выкину эту книгу тоже .

Comment: @МагомедАзизов, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)